# HOW TO Excel remove duplicates based on an 2 separate columns

Tags: excel

I have data in an excel over 2000 rows. Column B contains duplicates, I'd like to remove the duplicates if Column F = NO (hopefully my image shows up, otherwise example table below).
[What my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSPig.png)

| Column A | Column B | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WEED CONTROL | NC_1014_93979 | Yes |
| WEED CONTROL | NC_1014_93979 | No |
| PEST ANIMAL | NC_1015_82299 | Yes |
| PEST ANIMAL | NC_1015_82299 | No |
| WEED CONTROL | NC_1014_93579 | Yes |
| PEST ANIMAL | NC_1012_508225 | No |

So in my image the rows highlighted Yellow are the duplicate records I need to remove.

or as follows

| Column A | Column B | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WEED CONTROL | NC_1014_93979 | Yes |
| PEST ANIMAL | NC_1015_82299 | Yes |
| WEED CONTROL | NC_1014_93579 | Yes |
| PEST ANIMAL | NC_1012_508225 | No |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=FILTER(A1:C6,(COUNTIFS(A1:A6,A1:A6,B1:B6,B1:B6)=1)+((COUNTIFS(A1:A6,A1:A6,B1:B6,B1:B6)>1))*(C1:C6="Yes"))
```

[image]

Comment: FANTASITC! This did what I was looking for. I put the formula in and then copied the results to a fresh tab (paste values). Thank you very much for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

On the Data ribbon tab is a button for Remove Duplicates for this

[image]